# Physical Drives Unmounting After Standby?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive

I have 3 physical drives in my desktop, 1 for the operating system, and 2 for data. However, upon returning from standby, the 2 data drives no longer appear under Windows Explorer. They're not visible under Disk Management either.

Drives are SATA running in AHCI mode. OS is Windows 7 x64 Ultimate.

Anyone have any idea as to why I'm losing two of my drives afer a return from extended standby? (~8 hours)

Comment: Wow! That's .... bizarre. Are you up-to-date on your BIOS?

Comment: do your drives show up if you run "scan for hardware changes" from device manager?

Comment: Yes, November 2009 BIOS version.

Comment: No, they do not. Only after a restart do they show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reformatted, problem solved.